# how to toggle collapse content right to left beside icon bootstrap 4

Tags: toggle, bootstrap-4

i am unable to toggle content right to left beside icon  can any one can assist me

```
<div class="container=fluid">
    <div class="pos-f-t ">
        <div class="collapse " id="navbarToggleExternalContent">

            <ul class="navbar-nav  flex-row-reverse ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link">Right Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar-item">
                    <a class="nav-link">Right Link 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark ">
            <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon "></span>
            </button>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which version of bootstrap 4 you are working? can you add it in fiddle?

Comment: Could you add a bit more info, are you looking to have the links slide in from the right?

Comment: i am using bootstrap 4 i need exactly like below link using bootstrap 4 http://phppot.com/demo/header-menu-horizontal-expand-collapse-using-jquery/

Comment: Check this answer (and comments): https://stackoverflow.com/a/47236506/8918893

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nghy2n88/3/ check this

Comment: hi thx but i need it ti slide horizontaly

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="">demo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-dark" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.navbar-collapse {
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    left: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    display: block;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapsing {
    height: auto !important;
    margin-left: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.navbar-collapse.show {
    left: 0;
}
```

test it: https://www.codeply.com/go/yggim0FPTG